# how to query min and max values from table and show it like ranges/sequences?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

I have a table like this one (table):

```
id  |   from  | to   |  count
1   |   1     | 25   |  25
1   |   26    | 50   |  25
1   |   76    | 100  |  25
1   |   1501  | 1525 |  25
```

and what I want is group in "full" ranges like this one:

```
id  |   from |  to   |  count
1   |   1    |  50   |  50
1   |   76   |  100  |  25
1   |   1501 |  1525 |  25
```

I'm using MySQL and my (horrible) query doesn't work properly because I don't return what I want.

```
SELECT id, MIN(from), MAX(to), SUM(count)
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING (MAX(to)-MIN(from)+1) = SUM(count)
```

Comment: Why does everything have id == 1?

Comment: This is a Classic Gaps and Islands

Comment: You should *really* consider renaming those column names and your table name.

Comment: because i have to group-by (id) too, it´s doesn´t matter for the purposes of the problem

Comment: How do you want to create those ranges? Do want to group "full" ranges? Please explain a little more.

Comment: Quite so! @Fuzzzzel thanks!! My actual table is larger than the trivial example I posted.

Comment: id seems rather meaningless in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following data set is a little more complicated than that provided in the question...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,val_from  INT NOT NULL
,val_to INT NOT NULL
,count INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,25,25),
(2,26,35,12),
(3,36,50,13),
(4,76,100,25),
(5,1501,1525,25);


SELECT MIN(val_from) start
     , MAX(val_to) finish
     , SUM(count) total 
  FROM 
     (
       SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN val_from <= @prev_val_to + 1 THEN @i := @i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev_val_to := val_to prev_val_to 
         FROM my_table
            , (SELECT @prev_val_to := null, @i:=1) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) x
GROUP BY i;
+-------+--------+-------+
| start | finish | total |
+-------+--------+-------+
|     1 |     50 |    50 |
|    76 |    100 |    25 |
|  1501 |   1525 |    25 |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
   id, 
   case when [From] <= 50 then 1
        when [From] <= 100 then 51
        when [From] <= 1525 then 101 end [From],
   case when [From] <= 50 then 50
        when [From] <= 100 then 100
        when [From] <= 1525 then 1525 end [to],
   Sum(count) count
From table 
group by id, case when [From] <= 50 then 1
              when [From] <= 100 then 51 
              when [From] <= 1525 then 101 end
```